# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular

Tags: angular

i try to make a get request from Angular running on localhost:4200
to a spring boot webservice on localhost:8080 ... and i got CORS error.. when i try to make a proxy config as the documentation of Angular 7 suggests 
https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy

proxy.config.json

```
    {
        "/erp/*": {
            "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
            "secure": false
       }
    }
```

and in package.json

```
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

so i still get the same error..

Comment: add "changeOrigin: true" and "secure: false" to your proxy.

Comment: obviously my code contains "secure": false , and "changeOrigin" actually is for accessing a backend that's not a localhost.

Comment: @Helix, I think being different ports makes this different origins

Comment: i tried everything...

Answer (score 0):

these ways of proxy configs doesn't work for me.. i just included the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from the backend and everything works perfectly fine.. 
in my case the backend is spring boot .. there's an annotation that include this header automatically which is "@CrossOrigin" 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your Angular app. It's just your backend doesn't recognize your angular app because they are running as separate apps. What you need to know is you need to tell your backend that the one sending the request (in this case your Angular app) is known to you. This is the concept of Cross origin.  So your solution is the right solution for this problem. Another thing you can do is render your angular as a spring boot app.

Comment: yeah i know there's nothing wrong with angular.. i'm talking about the proxy solution angular offers in its docs..it doesn't work...